# Why use Phalcon's Assets Manager to apply Filters?

Tags: php, sass, phalcon

I'm creating an app in Phalcon which contains a theme manager. A theme is nothing more that a collection of `.scss` and `.volt` files. Naturally, these `.scss` are built before being used.

I'm been testing Phalcon's assets manager. Apart from some difficulties creating custom filters, etc, I started wondering: why would someone build their files all the time? This would make each request much slower. Does Phalcon cache these assets?

Furthermore, when developing themes or doing a lot of frontend work it is useful to watch the source sass files for changes. Is this possible in Phalcon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/master/api/Phalcon_Assets_Collection.html) using `->setTargetPath()` on assets collection makes it possible to save all selected files into one location. If you have some scripts you always include to your page, you can marge them to one file, and meantime minify thanks to filters filters. Code snipped would be somewhat like that:

```
$controller->assets->collection('jsGlobal')
    ->addJs('libs/jquery.js', true)
    ->addJs('libs/jquery-ui.js', true)
    ->setTargetPath('js/global.js')
    ->setTargetUri('js/global.js')
    ->join(true)
    ->addFilter(new \Phalcon\Assets\Filters\Jsmin());
```

You may want to check if script it already built under that `js/global.js` location to prevent from building it over and over again on production. This way, when making your deploy script you can just implement deletion of certain files on your production server.

Projects I'm working on uses `less`. We installed `\lessc` library to manage to keep in repository only `.less` files.

And again, in development mode we're not even checking if file was changed - we assume is was and are recompiling it just always. For production purposes, PHP is written to check if certain scripts does exist and is compiling `.less` only if they dont.

Comment: So, basically, the filters only make sense if you check if the file changed. Don't you think it is more practical to `--watch` for `less` changes during development and build them all once in deployment?

Comment: May or may be not. Depends on files count and how hudge is project itself and what is done with compiled files afterwards and if youre using single-developer machine or multi-developer server. We found it just quicker to avoid checking file timestamps in development and straigtly rush into building them over again :)